# Xamarin Mobile - Label with type HTML doesn't display img on Android

Tags: xamarin.android

**Hello**

I have an issue with Xamarin Mobile Android, I'm using a label of type html and I wanted to display an online pic, the following sample code is working fine on IOS:

```
<Label TextType="Html" Text="&lt;img src='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'>&lt;/img>" />
```

But on Android it display like the following: [image]
[Powered by TinyTake Screen Capture](https://www.tinytake.com)

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0.1351
Please Advise.

Answer (score 1):

Label in Xamarin forms is designed for Display text in Xamarin.Forms. The Image tag is recommended.

I can't get it worked too, it displays the same as the picture which you provided.

It contains this sentence in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label):

> Displaying HTML in a Label is limited to the HTML tags that are
> supported by the underlying platform

Maybe this explained it, as it even couldn't add the colors to the text on android while the label works well on ios.

Comment: So, that seems iOS and Android takes the different strategy on the Label.